# How to covert a sbyte[] to BitArray? C#.Net

Tags: casting, bitarray

I'm trying to integrate two systems that deal with images. One system provides an image as a sbyte[] and the other uses a BitArray. I need to take the data from the [sbyte[]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x(VS.71).aspx) and convert it into a BitArray. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to convert the `sbyte[]` to a `byte[]` and then pass it into the normal `BitArray` constructor. If you're using .NET 3.5 that's easy with LINQ:

```
byte[] bytes = sbytes.Select(s => (byte) s).ToArray();
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

This is assuming you're executing in an unchecked context already. Otherwise you might want to make the conversion explicitly unchecked:

```
byte[] bytes = sbytes.Select(s => unchecked((byte) s)).ToArray();
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Comment: Cool, so how do I convert sbyte[] to byte[]. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: Did you read the whole of my answer? It shows you - twice!

Answer (score 0):

[BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2.aspx) has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx) that takes a byte array that you might try:

```
sbyte[] sbytes = ...
BitArray ba = new BitArray(sbytes.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray());
```